# Time stamp when the message has been picked up by listener on queue

Tags: java, jms, messaging

A Java program sends a message to queue and listener on the other end picks the message.

Is it possible for the java program to know the time stamp when the listener had picked up the message.

I know this can be achieved by listener sending a response to reply-queue. But does JMS infrastructure has any inbuilt field to tell the sender when the listener picked the message.

The messaging system is JMS spec compliant.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: NO. Write your own mechanism.